# how to get all changed cells which may belong to different pages of grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to get all the changed rows/columns in entire jqgrid and i use below 2 methods for that

var retRows = $('#list4').getChangedCells('all');
var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');

both these methods return changed cells/ dirty cells on that page .
Actually all the rows that have say column 10 value as "draft" i want to submit them all in one click of submit

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have say 100 records in total and i diplay 10 per page, now i have marked few records out of 100 as 'dirty'
i fetch dirty records using
 var retCol = $('#list4').getChangedCells('dirty');

but it doesnt returns all records marked dirty, instead only the records that are marked dirty and belongs to the page which is diplayed.